# sqlite select distinct row that column is greater than another

Tags: sqlite, select

I have the following bill table

```
barcode        name      amount      payments
12345          name a    123         0
12346          name a    125         125
12333          name a    133         10
12347          name b    125         125
12348          name c    100         90
```

I want to select distinct rows that amount minus payments is greater than zero

so I want to select only the following

```
         name a    
         name c
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have just edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name)
FROM bill
WHERE amount > payments
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like below... it will help you...

```
SELECT Distinct name from bill where (amount - payments) > 0
```

Comment: select distinct rows that 'amount minus payments' is greater than zero' is this Your question...? then Why you down vote this answer...?